# how to check if the geopoint lies within the closed polygon drawn on osmdroid bonus pack

Tags: polygon, osmdroid, geopoints

I am using osmdroid library in android along with osmdroid bonus pack. I have drawn the a polygon for states using the nominatim state polygonpoints. Now i want to check if the Geopoint lies within the drawn polygon. How do i do it?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Why don't you show us some code? E.g. how are you storing your geo points and what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2):

Please try Below Algorithm using Java

```html
class Point
{
    int x, y;

    Point()
    {}

    Point(int p, int q)
    {
        x = p;
        y = q;
    }
}

public class Position_Point_WRT_Polygon
{

    public static boolean onSegment(Point p, Point q, Point r)
    {
        if (q.x <= Math.max(p.x, r.x) && q.x >= Math.min(p.x, r.x)
                && q.y <= Math.max(p.y, r.y) && q.y >= Math.min(p.y, r.y))
            return true;
        return false;
    }

    public static int orientation(Point p, Point q, Point r)
    {
        int val = (q.y - p.y) * (r.x - q.x) - (q.x - p.x) * (r.y - q.y);

        if (val == 0)
            return 0;
        return (val > 0) ? 1 : 2;
    }

    public static boolean doIntersect(Point p1, Point q1, Point p2, Point q2)
    {

        int o1 = orientation(p1, q1, p2);
        int o2 = orientation(p1, q1, q2);
        int o3 = orientation(p2, q2, p1);
        int o4 = orientation(p2, q2, q1);

        if (o1 != o2 && o3 != o4)
            return true;

        if (o1 == 0 && onSegment(p1, p2, q1))
            return true;

        if (o2 == 0 && onSegment(p1, q2, q1))
            return true;

        if (o3 == 0 && onSegment(p2, p1, q2))
            return true;

        if (o4 == 0 && onSegment(p2, q1, q2))
            return true;

        return false;
    }

    public static boolean isInside(Point polygon[], int n, Point p)
    {
        int INF = 10000;
        if (n < 3)
            return false;

        Point extreme = new Point(INF, p.y);

        int count = 0, i = 0;
        do
        {
            int next = (i + 1) % n;
            if (doIntersect(polygon[i], polygon[next], p, extreme))
            {
                if (orientation(polygon[i], p, polygon[next]) == 0)
                    return onSegment(polygon[i], p, polygon[next]);

                count++;
            }
            i = next;
        } while (i != 0);

        return (count & 1) == 1 ? true : false;
    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Point polygon1[] = { new Point(0, 0), new Point(10, 0),
                new Point(10, 10),new Point(5, 5), new Point(0, 10) };
        int n = 5;

        Point p = new Point(5, 7);
        System.out.println("Point P(" + p.x + ", " + p.y
                + ") lies inside polygon1: " + isInside(polygon1, n, p));
        p = new Point(11, 11);
        System.out.println("Point P(" + p.x + ", " + p.y
                + ") lies inside polygon1: " + isInside(polygon1, n, p));

        Point polygon2[] = { new Point(0, 0), new Point(5, 5), new Point(5, 0) };
        n = 3;

        p = new Point(3, 3);
        System.out.println("Point P(" + p.x + ", " + p.y
                + ") lies inside polygon2: " + isInside(polygon2, n, p));
        p = new Point(5, 1);
        System.out.println("Point P(" + p.x + ", " + p.y
                + ") lies inside polygon2: " + isInside(polygon2, n, p));
        p = new Point(8, 1);
        System.out.println("Point P(" + p.x + ", " + p.y
                + ") lies inside polygon2: " + isInside(polygon2, n, p));

        Point polygon3[] = { new Point(0, 0), new Point(10, 0),
                new Point(10, 10), new Point(0, 10), new Point(5, 5) };
        n = 5;

        p = new Point(-1, 10);
        System.out.println("Point P(" + p.x + ", " + p.y
                + ") lies inside polygon3: " + isInside(polygon3, n, p));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

OSMBonusPack Polygon provides a "contains" method.

However, as described in the javadoc, this method returns correct results ONLY IF the Polygon has been drawn before, and if the MapView positioning has not changed.

So it's really fine for touch events detection, but can be inappropriate for various usages.

If it's not appropriate to your context, you will have to implement the feature.

Comment: can you please give any example with a polygon and a point? the contains method want MotionEvent as agrument and i dont know how to do that  and why it needs MotionEvent to check geopoints are inside polygon or not